# Why does Random Forest use randomness at all?

Tags: random-forest

My understanding of RF is you take a random selection of the data, as well as a random selection of the feature set. You then take the average of these decision trees to get a good guess, and your overfit should be kept in check by the fact that the trees are looking at different data/features.

But why is it necessary to do this randomly? Couldn't you just as well calculate all the permutations (up to some limit) and run the model on that?

Edit

To make it a bit more concrete, let's say I have some dataset with a billion rows of data and 10 features.

I could choose something like 2 features randomly selected. If I do that, there are 45 (10c2) pairs of features a tree could be picking. Now knowing there's 45 pairs, why don't I just evenly sample each pair, instead of sampling randomly? I'm not going to get a completely even set if I do say  a random 4500 trees. But I could just say I'll do 100 trees in each feature pair.

Comment: If you have a large enough set of data, you will hit your "up to some limit" rather quickly

Comment: Sure, and if some samples give a vastly different result than others maybe that's saying something about your model. But what about the feature set? If you have 10 features, you could easily find all the models using exactly 2 or 3 or something like that?

Comment: I suppose the answer is that if you aren't overfitting, you're unlikely to get any random sampling that differs much from any other?

Comment: Even surprisingly modest sets of data (in terms of n and p) yield astronomically large numbers of possible subsamples $\times$ feature-sets. Dealing with all such permutations is only going to be possible for quite small problems.

Comment: Look at the number of permutations. nCk explodes very quickly,  and you only have a finite amount of RAM to work with.

Comment: @Glen_b that doesn't address the point that you can do all the samples that are shallow. When you choose something random, you are also taking a small sample. So is there a reason that pretty much any sample will work?

Comment: @Carlos I'm not sure I follow your point but if you think my comment doesn't fully address the issue you need to edit your question to clarify. (In particular, it would be helpful if you could show some nontrivial examples where you have done what you propose.)

Comment: @Glen_b what I mean is simply that since there are many possible ways to draw a sampling, is there a reason why we should be comfortable that drawing just a few (which is what we're doing, right?) will give us a representative model?

Comment: Again, I suggest you put this in your question.